# There are 3 red balls and 2 white balls in a box.

Tags: probability, statistics

Now consider an experiment in which a ball is taken out from the box each time, then put back after its color observed, and one ball is put into again whose color is the same as the taking out one. if we repeat the experiment 4 times in succession, try to find the probability that we obtain a white ball in the 1st, 2nd times, and obtain a red ball in the 3rd, 4th times.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: i tried like this 2/5*2/5*3/5*3/5 but i think it's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability that the first ball is white is $\frac{2}{5}$ but then the white ball is returned and **another white ball is added**.

So you now have $6$ balls in which $3$ are red and $3$ are white, now the probability that the second ball is white is $\frac{3}{6}$, and so on...

The answer will be 
$\frac{2}{5}×\frac{3}{6}×\frac{3}{7}×\frac{4}{8}=\frac{3}{70}$

Comment: Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Probability of taking white ball with repetition in first two attempts is 2/5×2/5. 
Probability of taking white ball with repetition in first two attempts is 3/5×3/5. 
So the answer is 2/5×2/5×3/5×3/5

Comment: It's wrong. The answer is 3/70.